# Sortable Tables that are built dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to make my table be sortable.  I have found this script and i am able to get it to work on plain tables. http://yoast.com/articles/sortable-table/

The problem is in my application the table is being built dynamically through ajax calls to java webservices.  When i add the "sortable" class to the table it does not become sortable.  I have built another table exactly like it, with the same id's and class, except it is already built and the script works fine.

Any idea why this will not work when the table is dynamically built and how to make it work?

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran in the same issue before, what you have to do is recall the method after the ajax request is complete,  I recommend using : http://tablesorter.com/docs/

So you could run your ajax request

> $("#myTable").append(resultfromajax); $("#myTable").tablesorter();

Comment: That did it.  I used the other plugin and called it after the ajax.  Good to go! Thanks Rafael!

Answer (score 0):

After you have built your table, call `ts_makeSortable(table);` where `table` is the table's DOM object (ie one you get with `document.getElemenByID()`, not jQuery obj).